# How to handle infinite Links with react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently building a recipe book website based on ReactJS and react-router.
All my informations is saved in JSON and I'm handling all that using axios.
Now my question is, I have a grid with all my recipes, when I click on one is uses a Link to redirect me to another page, like this :
`<Link to={'/' + name} className="recipe-styler" id={name}>`

How can I redirect this so it will open a page and load the information of that.
I was thinking of just redirecting it to /detailedRecipe for example and parsing all the informations throught the Link, but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of dynamic routing with *react-router-dom* and using match params.

First, let's say you have 3 routes in the app, List view, Details view and a fallback route (error page for example). It would look something like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/recipes" component={ListComponent} />
    <Route path="/recipes/:id" component={DetailsComponent} />
    <Route component={ErrorPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now, you can set the links inside your grid to be something like this:

```
<Link to={`/recipes/${item.id}`} className="recipe-styler" />
```

Finally, when you click on the link, and router redirects to you the DetailsComponent, you can get the link id like this.

```
export class DetailsComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    if (match) {
      // This line is pseudocode. 
      // Use the id to get the item details from api, redux or wherever.
      api.get(params.id)
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Router will injects the match.params object when it resolves the route. Prop name from the params object depends on how you named it in the router declaration e.g.

```
<Route path="/recipes/:recipeId" component={DetailsComponent} /> // params.recipeId
<Route path="/recipes/:id" component={DetailsComponent} /> // params.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information! Works realy well.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.